# Enqueuing javascript files

Tags: jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to enqueue a JS file (located at /js/example-script.js), just to get an alert on page load.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

In my example-script.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  alert("hi");
});
```

And in my functions file:

```
function my_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'example-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example-script.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );
```

jQuery is loaded in my sources, so that's not the problem...

Comment: Try to change `example-script` handler name

Comment: Do you see any error in browser console?

Comment: please check  js file  included in head section your theme

Comment: second think check js conflict with other file

Comment: @JohnG could you look at my answer? I have posted a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a child theme ? In this case you have to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead of `get_stylesheet_template_uri()`which returns the parent theme uri
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory/#usage

Answer (score 1):

### Example for themes

I would recommend using [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) with [get_theme_file_uri](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_file_uri/) this allows child themes to overwrite this file.

> ### get_theme_file_uri() function
>
> Searches in the stylesheet directory before the template directory so
>   themes which inherit from a parent theme can just override one file.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'example-script', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/example-script.js' ), array('jquery'), null, true );
```

### Example for plugins

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'example-script', plugins_url('/js/example-script.js', __FILE__), array(), null );
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers correct - in my case I'd done it right, just wasn't loading the WP Footer, despite jQuery showing in my sources. As soon as I added in get_footer(), all worked fine.